# Examples of topological spaces with canonical bases with the following property (redivisibility)

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, big-list

Let us say that a family of sets $\mathcal{S}$ is *redivisible* if, for any $S_1, S_2\in \mathcal{S}$, the intersection $S_1\cap S_2$ is the union of **finitely many** sets from $\mathcal{S}$.

**Which (classes of) topological spaces have a canonical basis which is redivisible?**

Some examples I came up with:

1. Order topology, with basis given by all intervals.
2. Preorder topology, with basis given by upper sets.
3. Ultrametric spaces, with basis given by open balls.
4. While metric spaces don't seem to have this property in general, the euclidean topology with basis given by all open boxes does have it.

Is there any other notable example?

This is a vague question where by **canonical** I mean the following: definitional basis, a basis that you would give when describing/defining the topology.

Comment: What does "canonical" mean? All spaces have at least one such basis: the whole topology

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I do not know this topology: could you define it? I am really curious about.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: I'm just saying that if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, then the whole of $\tau$ is a redivisible base for $\tau$ itself

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Oh, yeah! This is sure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's pointless

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I am specifically interested in tame topological model-theoretic structures where the topology has a basis that is uniformly definable in the structure language. For example in the reals as an ordered field the euclidean topology has a basis the is definable using only the order (boxes) or using the field language plus order (e.g. formula $\|x-y\|_2<z$). Nevertheless, I am happy to ask this question in a more vague way, where by canonical I mean a typical example of a basis which you would give when introducing/describing the space. I will edit the question.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma The question is vague, not pointless.

Comment: If every space has such a basis, the notion is thus pointless. It adds nothing.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma My edit to the question I would hope makes it clear that "the whole topology" was not something I meant with "canonical basis".

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments by Antonio this question is void/meaningless. If $(X,\tau)$ is *any* space, then $\mathcal{S}=\tau$ is a basis (you can call it canonical, which is itself a vague undefined term anyway) and it's trivially redivisible as it's closed under finite intersections, being a topology.